# Getting all pixel values from raster image in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, pixel

I am using a CHIRPS raster image on ArcGIS 10.6 and there is no attribute table, I need the pixel values as it is the individual rainfall data for the stations to perform further statistics on.

How can I get all the pixel values? W

hen I use the identify icon it the pixel value does come up, however it is impractical to do this for an entire country.

Comment: Sounds like you want [Zonal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm). You will need country borders, for example as vector data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the attribute table of raster data, you need to convert the Pixel Type from floating point to signed integer. This can be done if you have Spatial Analyst extension.

With Spatial Analyst you can use Raster Calculator to convert the Pixel type from floating point to signed integer using the following formula:

```
Int(RoundDown("YourRasterImage"))     # You can use RoundUp() also, it is up to you
```

I tested CHIRPS raster data with a pixel type of floating point, the attribute table is not active:

[image]

After converting the pixel type to signed integer using the above formula, the attribute table becomes active:

[image]

Here is the attribute table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need the data in text format.

So you could export your shapefile in ascii (conversion tools > from raster) or, if you do not have too many pixels, convert your raster the points (then you can read the pixels values in the attribute table, add labels on each point and further export this table as a text file  utilities  > feature to ascii)